# WooCommerce Product to be purchased only once regardless of the quantity and the user

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, woocommerce-subscriptions, woocommerce-bookings

I have a property site, I have rooms as products in WooCommerce. There is an option to rent the room whether for 6 months or 12 months. I did a workaround and for 6 months the product quantity will be 1 and for 12 months the quantity will be 2.

E.g 
For 6 months price is 2000 (quantity 1)
For 12 months price 4000(quantity 2)

Now what I want is to restrict the product (room) to be purchased only once.

Link : https://heyrooms.com/property/morden-apartment-balham-london-6/

The book now button add the product in the cart according to the time period in the drop down above.

Edit: I can't use a variable product options. Because it's not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose a different approach to solving the problem.
Why don't you create the products as variable instead of simple. You can then set the price accordingly for 6m/1y. Then just make the stock quantity as 1.
You should then be good to go.

Comment: The main problem here is I am not directly interacting with woocommerce. I am using a property plugin ere to manage properties and I did some custom work around to purchase the properties because ere don't provide the functionality. I used quick buy plugin api to purchase by clicking on purchase button.

Comment: You can have a look here https://heyrooms.com/property/morden-apartment-balham-london-6/

Comment: Are you trying to do all this from somewhere other than the site itself? Maybe I don't understand the whole scenario clearly but if a button is what you need then you can just make one and link it to the checkout url for a particular product (or variation) using the product ID. See this: https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-custom-add-cart-urls-ultimate-guide/

Comment: yup that's what I am doing at the moment. i do realize now that i can use vairations with it too. But still I can't use variations now. Because my client is not comfortable with it. Can we do it like that when the purchase is made the stock drops to zero?

Comment: You can add an action to `woocommerce_thankyou` hook which will find all the purchased products and then use `$product->set_stock_quantity(0)` over each product to set the qty as 0.

Comment: You can see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42533543/12675543

Comment: Thank you so much I will try it and respond back immediately.