# What hook to use once order is created in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I have created the following plugin, which is supposed to send a POST HTTP request to an external server when a Woocommerce order is created. However, this is not happening: no request received on the external server, nothing is showing up in `wp-content/debug.log` (I do have `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );` in `wp-config.php`). What am I doing wrong?

```php
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: MyPlugin
 */


function my_hook($order_id) {
    $url = "https://example.com/do_something";
    $data = wp_remote_post($url, array(
        'headers'     => array(
            'Authorization' => "Token my_token",
            'Content-Type'  => 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        ),
        'body'        => json_encode(array('order_id' => $order_id)),
        'method'      => 'POST',
        'data_format' => 'body',
    ));
}
add_action(
    'woocommerce_new_order',
    'my_hook'
);

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Since WooCommerce 4.3.0 the correct hook to be used is `woocommerce_checkout_order_created`,  to send a POST HTTP request to an external server when an order is created. So your code is going to be:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_created', 'my_hooked_function_callback', 10 );

function my_hooked_function_callback( $order ) {

    $url = "https://example.com/do_something";

    $data = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
        'headers'     => array(
            'Authorization' => "Token my_token",
            'Content-Type'  => 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        ),
        'body'        => json_encode( array( 
           'order_id' => $order->get_id() 
        ) ),
        'method'      => 'POST',
        'data_format' => 'body',
    ) );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

This [hook is located](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.5.2/includes/class-wc-checkout.php#L403) inside [`create_order()` method for `WC_Checkout`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.5.2/includes/class-wc-checkout.php#L304-L418) Class.

**Note:** The code will not work for manual created orders via admin.

---

**Additional notes:**

- To update order meta data **once order is created** you will use instead the action hook `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta`, *with 2 available arguments: `$order_id` and `$data` (the posted data)*.
- To update order data or meta data **before order is created** you will use instead the action hook `woocommerce_checkout_create_order`  *with 2 available arguments: *$order* and `$data` (the posted data)*.
- To update **order items** data or meta data **before order is created** you will use instead the action hook `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item`  *with 2 available arguments: **$item**, `$cart_item_key`, `$values`, `$order`*.

Related: [How to debug in WooCommerce 3+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61740111/how-to-debug-in-woocommerce-3/61754061#61754061)

Answer (score 2):

If you go inside class-wc-checkout you will find the create_order function which trigger these hooks just before ending:

```
        /**
         * Action hook to adjust order before save.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', $order, $data );

        // Save the order.
        $order_id = $order->save();

        /**
         * Action hook fired after an order is created used to add custom meta to the order.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', $order_id, $data );

        /**
         * Action hook fired after an order is created.
         *
         * @since 4.3.0
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_created', $order );
```

Maybe you just have to use one of those?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer use `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed`.

> Rather than `woocommerce_thankyou` hook,
> `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` hook is the relevant hook.
> `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` hook will be called only once
> and you will not need to add meta for each product and make additional
> calls to keep check for code to run only once. As,
> `woocommerce_thankyou` can be called multiple times that is each time
> thankyou page loads.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72195252/3261332