# Detect when a user changes any of their billing details (user meta)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce site that I want to detect if a user changes any of their billing details. I've had a look around and found this snippet:

```
add_filter( 'insert_user_meta', function( $meta, $user, $update ) {
  if( true !== $update ) return $meta;
  $old_meta = get_user_meta( $user->ID );
  if( $old_meta[ 'first_name' ] !== $meta[ 'first_name' ] ) {
    //* Do something
  }
  return $meta;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Will this fire everytime an update is made to the user meta? How can I add in all the following fields to see if any change:

- Company
- Billing address line 1
- Billing address line 2
- City
- Postcode
- Country
- County

Or alternatively, is there a woocommerce hook for this?

Would something like this work?

```
function my_profile_update( $user_id ) {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['pass1'] ) || '' == $_POST['pass1'] ) {
        return;
    }

    // password changed...
}
add_action( 'profile_update', 'my_profile_update' );
```

Comment: Doesn't `$meta` and `$oldmeta` contain all the information like Company, Billing address's etc?

Comment: Maybe this answer to this question may be able to help you out a bit, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22843504/how-to-get-customer-details-from-order-in-woocommerce

Comment: @IsThisJavascript It's not quite related to the order because they can go into their account and change their details without ordering anything new. I guess it's more of a user meta question???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a user edit address from woocommerce my account page in frontend, there is a hook available for edit address through which you can check and achieve your work. The hook as follow -

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_customer_save_address', $user_id, $load_address );
```

where `$load_address` return `'billing'` whenever a user edit billing fields.

Comment: Ah ok, so could I do something like `add_action( 'woocommerce_customer_save_address', 'update_meta_info', 10, 2 );
function update_meta_info( $user_id, $load_address ) { //do something }`?

Comment: Exactly, and do a checking within your function that `if( $load_action != 'billing' ) return;`

Comment: Ok great, one thing I don't understand is how I break down each line of the address using `$load_address`?

Comment: You can get all the submitted address data within your function, if you print `$_POST` array

Comment: I've updated my question with what I want to do... I want to put the address into the data array. Is that possible?

Comment: Then you can build a array from `$_POST` data with all billing information and replace in data or just simply replace `'data'  => $_POST` to shore all submitted data all together.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if the hook works, it is triggered for all Wordpress users, not only customers.

But I would recommend not to compare on data that a user can enter. In your case if he made a typo in his first name (like uppercase first letter), comparision fails and one can never correct that.

What you are looking for is one of the account page hooks. But unfortunately I can only point out a direction.