# Customer ID is 0 in woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta hook

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When creating a Woocommerce order using the "Add Order" screen in the Wordpress admin, if I retrieve the order using wc_get_order() in a callback attached to woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta, I have noticed that the Customer ID is 0 - despite the fact that I have selected a customer. The code I am writing uses this data to sync to an external API so my question is: Why is this ID empty and is there a way to get the correct ID?

A simplified version of the code would be:

```
add_action('woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', 'processOrder', 10, 1);

function processOrder($order_id){
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    die(print_r($order->get_customer_id(),1));
}
```

Comment: have you tried testing User ID from the Order ID using user_id
 
$user_id = $order->get_user_id();

to see if this gets an id

Comment: Hi Brad, yeah I was/am actually using get_user_id in my real-life code, I just modified it slightly here to get the point across a little better. It's probably important to note that the user/customer ids are set correctly when an order is updated - it's only missing with a new order. This makes me believe that I'm probably using the wrong hook....but the documentation for the hooks on woocommerce is not really helpful for finding the right one.

Comment: By the way, I did also print_r the entire order object and can see that it's set to 0 in general, so it's not just one of the functions being a pain.

Comment: actually look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22843504/how-to-get-customer-details-from-order-in-woocommerce/57562904#57562904

Comment: Thanks man, but unfortunately that didn't help. I should also probably point out that both the billing and shipping details are also empty at this point...which again makes me believe that I'm using the wrong hook (as it looks like the customer data is saved after my code is run).

Comment: can you share your full code if possible ill have a look for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the priority you're using.
See attached image:
[image]

The customer id is saved in `add_action( 'woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', 'WC_Meta_Box_Order_Data::save', 40, 2 );` where priority is `40`.
Setting your priority greater than 40 then it should work.

Comment: Ahhh! Thank you, will test it and get back to you