Force setting billing address and product during manual order creation in WooCommerce HPOS
I'm using the latest WooCommerce version with HPOS. To avoid manual orders created via the admin panel (backend) with specific empty values (no products and no shipping postcode), I tried to create a function which stops creating the order, if the billing postcode is empty and no product is added to the order.
Here my code attempt
// During Order creation in the admin area - force to set at least one procduct and billing postalcode to avoid issues on the order overview screen and more
function avoid_orders_wout_b_postalcode_a_wout_products_9sadfM324($post_id, $post) {

    // Get the order object
    $order = wc_get_order($post_id);
    
    // Check if the order has products
    $items = $order->get_items();
    if (empty($items)) {
        // Add an error message to WooCommerce admin notices
        WC_Admin_Notices::add_custom_notice('no_products_added_error', 'ERROR YCNC0084 - ' . __('You cannot create an order without adding any products', 'nm-framework'));
        // Redirect to the edit order screen
        wp_redirect(admin_url('post.php?post=' . $post_id . '&action=edit'));
        exit;
    }

    // Check for postal code in billing and shipping address
    $billing_postcode = $order->get_billing_postcode();
    // $shipping_postcode = $order->get_shipping_postcode();

    // if (empty($billing_postcode) && empty($shipping_postcode)) {
     if ( empty($billing_postcode) ) {
        // Add an error message to WooCommerce admin notices
        WC_Admin_Notices::add_custom_notice('no_billing_postalcode_error', 'ERROR YCNC0024 - ' . __('You cannot create an order without a billing postal code', 'nm-framework'));   
        // Redirect to the edit order screen
        wp_redirect(admin_url('post.php?post=' . $post_id . '&action=edit'));
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', 'avoid_orders_wout_b_postalcode_a_wout_products_9sadfM324', 99, 2); 
// must higher then 40 according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/59726544/11946596

Unfortunately, I can save / create the order if I only add the postal code… It should not save the order if any of these two are not set.
Any idea how to fix it?

Note that on WordPress Admin, when you click on "add new order", an empty order is created and saved automatically to the database, so the order number is already displayed on that new order page, before filling it up.
