# Update ACF field after a Woocommerce order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm developing a WordPress plugin using ACF and WooCommerce.

I created two Custom Post Types. The first one is "Clients" and the second one "Actions".
The purpose of this plugin is to list all the clients (from a company) and list every actions of this company.

In the CPT Clients, I'm using an ACF number field to store their credits, for each client.
All actions cost credits, I created a system that updates the total amount of the client's credits, by subtracting the cost of the action.

Now, I want to allow clients to buy credits if they need them.
To do it, I choose WooCommerce. I created some "virtual" products.

My question is : after an order, how can I update the total amount of client's credits ?
I don't know WooCommerce at all, I tried to read and to search but I didn't success.
What functions can I use ?
To resume, I want update the ACF number field of my CPT by adding the credits that have been purchased by the client.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try hooking into one of these actions:

`woocommerce_new_order`: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3611d4643791bad87a0d3e6e73e031bb80447417/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-order-data-store-cpt.php#L172-L175

`woocommerce_new_order_item` : https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3611d4643791bad87a0d3e6e73e031bb80447417/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-order-item-functions.php#L39

There you can get the User from the Order via `$order->get_customer_id()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57562904/557225

And then use `update_field` on your CPT's https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/

Hope it helps!