# How does WooCommerce asssign a customer_id?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm building a WooCommerce site and plan to treat all customers as guests, meaning there's no reason to force them to create accounts.  I interact with the system using the REST API to get information about each order.

Within an order there is a field called "customer_id". I assume that this value will be unique for each user but am finding that it isn't. How is this value assigned?

- Cookie?
- IP Address?
- Hash of some customer data?

Additionally, I'm calling the API endpoint to get a list of customers and receiving an empty list. Is this because none of the users has created an account? Why don't I get information about the users who've bought products without registering?

Comment: WooCommerce "Orders" are just a custom post type, so all the orders are stored in _wp_posts_ and its order information in stored into _wp_postmeta_ tables. There are many ways to retrieve order information which you can read more about in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57562904/10497022) as well as here [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44708344/10497022). This [specific solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36336182/10497022) retrieves data from orders made by guests (not logged in users) where you can query it directly from the database.

Comment: Also, don't get confused with the `customer_id` and `user_id`. They are not the same. [See image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/24649833/112545883-a3650800-8db0-11eb-82dc-6f040bdae2a8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out they don't.

Guest accounts always have a customer_id of 0.

If I want to keep the customers straight I need to rely on different data such as the email.

Comment: Wrong in some way: Guest users for sure have a **User ID** = 0 (order meta key `_customer_user` in `wp_postmeta` table), but if you go in database to `wp_wc_customer_lookup` table, each user (guest or not) has a unique **customer ID** different from the User ID.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec  According to the official REST API, it says about customer_id within the Order object "User ID who owns the order. 0 for guests. Default is 0." There may be some other data within the database, but I can't get to it through the API.

Comment: That is not the customer ID, but the user ID that you retrieve in wp_user, wp_usermeta,  wp_wc_customer_lookup table and wp_wc_order_product_lookup. The real Customer ID is only referenced in wp_wc_customer_lookup table for instance. In another way, when you say "customer ID", you refer to the user ID in the database. Never mind of the rest API, the customer ID is the user ID, excepting in wp_wc_customer_lookup table… END.